# How do I check whether an object is an arguments object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm in ES5 strict mode, so the solution

```
function isArguments(item) {
    return item.callee !== undefined;
}
```

unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Any particular engine or does the solution have to be generic?

Comment: Do you just want to check for an `Object` with a `length` property?

Comment: Note that the method above isn't completely reliable even when you're not in strict mode: `alert(isArguments({"callee" : "test"}));` - I agree with alex that checking for the `length` property is a reasonable compromise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
function isArguments( item ) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call( item ) === '[object Arguments]';
}
```

Comment: +1. Notice that the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#isArguments) and [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#isArguments) libraries provide this as a helper function `_.isArguments`.

Comment: Note that ES6 adds [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag), which provides a way to customize the result of `Object.prototype.toString`. So it is possible to break this check in recent versions of JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

[William's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7656333/1529630) is right, but some explanations may be useful.

In ECMAScript 5, the only thing that characterizes Arguments objects is their internal [[Class]], as seen in [§10.6 Arguments Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6):

> When CreateArgumentsObject is called the following steps are
>   performed:
>
> - Let *obj* be the result of creating a new ECMAScript object.
> - Set the [[Class]] internal property of *obj* to `"Arguments"`.
> - Return *obj*

[[Class]] is an internal property common to all objects, whose value is a String which classifies the object. This is explained in [§8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2):

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property is defined by this
>   specification for every kind of built-in object.
>
> The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to
>   distinguish different kinds of objects.

Moreover, note that host objects won't be problematic:

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be
>   any String value except one of `"Arguments"`, [...]

Therefore, to identify an Arguments object you only need to check its class.

You can do that using [§15.2.4.2 `Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2):

> - Let *O* be the result of calling [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) passing the **this** value as the argument.
> - Let *class* be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *O*.
> - Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, *class*, and `"]"`.

Therefore, you can use [`Function.prototype.call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) to call that method with the `this` value set to the object you want to check. The returned string will be `'[object Arguments]'` if, and only if, it's an Arguments object.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Arguments]'
```

Note that isn't completely foolproof, because the global `Object` could have been shadowed by a local one, or the global `Object` or its `toString` property could have been modified.

However, there is no better way:

> Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program
>   to access that value except through `Object.prototype.toString` (see
>   [15.2.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)).

Answer (score 1):

Generating and comparing strings to determine the type of an object is a little fuzzy. Like @bergi suggested, I think [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#isArguments) is doing it a more convenient way.   Condensed into one function it is:

```
function isArguments(value) {
    return !!value && typeof value == 'object' && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, 'callee') && !Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(value, 'callee');
}
```