# How to detect arguments object in ie8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

following up from [How do I check whether an object is an arguments object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656280/how-do-i-check-whether-an-object-is-an-arguments-object-in-javascript)

Neither of the solutions given work in IE8. Is there any way to detect whether an object is an arguments object in IE8?

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support "strict mode", so checking for `callee` should work.

Comment: Like @Rocket said. You'd just want to short circuit the `.callee` test since it throws in strict mode. `return Object.prototype.toString.call( item ) === '[object Arguments]' || !!item.callee;`

Answer (score 4):

@Rocket & @cliffs_of_insanity are correct, I must have tested wrong initially.

All together, I arrived at:

```
var isArguments = function(obj) {
    return (obj != null) && // since undefined == null
        ((Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Arguments]') ||
            (!!obj.callee)); // fixes for ie8 non-strict-mode
};
```

For more info on the arguments object's history and why this works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: Note that it will return `true` in all browsers for `isArguments({callee: true})` etc.

Comment: See how it is fixed in underscore: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/4c534babce217abb7e13bd47efcb399e47ef9cca/underscore.js#L1234-1247