# How to refer to the Arguments class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor, instanceof, typechecking

Simply put,
in JavaScript, the variable `arguments` (through which you can get all arguments of current function) is not of type `Array`, but the console says it is of type `Arguments`.

You can't get this class by simply typing `Arguments` (like you do with eg. `String`), so I get a reference of it like:

```
Arguments = function(){return arguments.constructor;}();
```

so I can type check like this:

```
function foo() {
    bar = arguments;
}
foo();
bar instanceof Arguments;
```

**Is there a way to directly refer to the `Arguments` object?** (Instead of generating it out, as in the former snippet?)

Ps.: The project I am working on is a type checking system for debugging purposes. You could assign types for object variables like `MyClass.fileds = {speed: Number, color: String}`, that are then checked when assigned. And I came around using `Arguments` objects, and it would have been nice just to write `{args: Arguments}`.

Comment: "Also, please, don't just ask why do I want that..." -- Well, this seems like an XY problem, why do you want or need to do that?

Comment: I think the better question is, what are you trying to achieve that requires you to "directly refer to the arguments object"? The answer to that will allow for better approaches

Comment: If you just have to have it as an Array, you can do `[].slice.call(arguments)`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: There isn't an actual `Arguments` type to access or modify -- [10.6 Arguments Object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6). Despite `"Arguments"` being assigned to their internal `[[Class]]` property (step 4) to *mark* them, they are otherwise plain `Object`s (step 6). http://jsfiddle.net/JBps7/

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs. In my experience on SO, "*why do you want that?*" very often leads to important, very productive and informative discussions on better strategies to achieve the original poster's goals. Even if it's not helpful to you, it may be helpful to other readers that might have a similar problem. If you're just asking out of curiosity, that's fine, but let's not discourage constructive discussions about the problem at hand.

Comment: Well, perhaps you are right.

I need it solely to do nice type checking, ie to use
`bar instanceof Arguments;`

So, any `Arguments` object, that gives true for the former expression would also be a sufficient solution.

Well, in that case, I guess, I just need to dig around regarding how `instaneof` works.

Comment: Ps.: The project I am working on is a type checking system for debugging purposes. You could assing types for object variables like `MyClass.fileds = {speed: Number, color: String}`, that are then checked when assigned. And I came around using `Arguments` objects, and it would have been nice just to write `{args: Arguments}`

Comment: Sounds like a cool project. That's exactly the kind of context that  would make a question like this much more interesting. I've edited your question to include that information as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Arguments` class. The `Arguments` variable that you have is just the `Object` constructor:

```
function(){return arguments.constructor;}() === Object
```

Each `arguments` object is a plain object which inherits from `Object.prototype`. In sloppy mode, its indexed properties are setters/getters for the named parameter variables, but except that and [its internal `[[Class]]` value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) it is an ordinary object.

If you are interested in `Arguments` only to do that `instanceof` check, you should have a look at the [How do I check whether an object is an arguments object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7656280/1048572) question.