# How to make a function work with an arguments object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, arguments

I'm a beginner completing an assignment where I need to write a function that passes various tests, and I've passed all requirements except for: "should work on an arguments object". I think that it may have something to do with when argument object length is anything other than 2, but I'm not sure. Thank you in advanced for any help you can provide! Here are the requirements: [image]

And here is my code:

```js
_.first = function (array, n) {

  let argArr = arguments[0];
  let argN = arguments[1];

  if (!Array.isArray(argArr)) {
    let newArr = [];
    return newArr;
  } else {
    if (argN <= 0 || isNaN(argN)){
      let newArr = [];
      newArr.push(argArr[0]);
      return newArr;
    } else if (argN > argArr.length) {
      return argArr;
    } else if (argN >= 0 && argN <= argArr.length) {
      let newArr = []
      for (let i=0; i<argN; i++) {
          newArr.push(argArr[i])
      }
      return newArr;
    } else {
      let newArr = [];
      return newArr
    }
  }

};
```

And here's the console with the various arguments being tested:

[image]

Comment: Your issue is that `Array.isArray(argArr)` is false when `argArr` is an `arguments` object, so your first `if` block (where you return an empty array) is running and ending the function. I'm actually not sure how to check if a variable is an `Arguments` object; a quick check shows that `arguments` objects just have an `Object` prototype/constructor.

Comment: There is no way to reliably determine if an object is an `arguments` object, so we have to look for hints that an object might be an `arguments` object. The answer is basically: check if `argArr.toString() == "[object Arguments]"` as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7656280/710446. (This question is more or less a duplicate of that one, since your fundamental problem is detecting `arguments` input and then changing behavior based on that decision.)

Comment: @apsillers I'd guess one is not supposed to do the `Array.isArray` test at all. Just assume that the first argument is an array-like object.

Comment: @Bergi That's what I thought, except the final requirement (down under the error message, before the OP's code) is "should return an empty array if array is not an array" -- which, of course, the `arguments` requirement violates (so we must read it as a special exception to the final requirement).